# Optimization for MIPS sum array

Tags: assembly, mips

I have some codes to sum array 50 times. Now I'm asked to reduce this code by at least 1 instructions. All I could think of was to increase this loop to 100 times and then add one element per loop. But this would increase the instruction counts a lot.

```
      addi $t1, $0, 50 
LOOP: lw $s1, 0($s0) 
      add $s2, $s2, $s1 
      lw $s1, 4($s0) 
      add $s2, $s2, $s1 
      addi $s0, $s0, 8 
      subi $t1, $t1, 1 
      bne $t1, $0, LOOP
```

Note that you can only rewrite this code, not write another sumArray algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one instruction less, by "combining" the address and the loop counter, thereby summing the array backwards:

```
      addi $t1, $s0, 400   # $t1 = $s0 + 50*2*sizeof(word)
LOOP: lw $s1, -4($t1) 
      add $s2, $s2, $s1 
      lw $s1, -8($t1) 
      add $s2, $s2, $s1 
      sub $t1, $t1, 8 
      bne $t1, $s0, LOOP
```

Comment: I see your point, but doesn't this reduce a lot of instructions? your code will run the loop 25 times plus 1 = 151 instructions while the original has 351 instructions?

Comment: Oops. The 200 at the beginning should be 400. It should do the same number of iterations as the original code, just with one instruction less per iteration.

Comment: for the last line bne, why do you compare with $s0, I thought it is just $0?

Comment: Because before the loop I set `$t1 = array + 50*2*sizeof(word)` (i.e. just past the end of the array). The exit condition therefore becomes `$t1 == array`, i.e. `$t1 == $s0`.